# Синонимизировать градиенты

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать [gradients](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradients) к метке [градиент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82). У нас предпочтение отдаётся русскоязычным меткам, к тому же метка [градиент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82) имеет хорошее описание.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метки объединены и синонимизированы.